# How can I call an instance method from within my uncaught exception handler function?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set an uncaught exception handler for my app. I'd like to call an instance method in my `AppDelegate` when an exception occurs so I can clean up some stuff and write a few logs to the local database, but I can't figure out a clean way to do this.

I tried with a static reference to the instance, and that works, but I really don't like it. I shouldn't have to retain some static crap during my entire runtime just to be able to clean up after a crash.

Ideally I'd like to just add an `(AppDelegate *)` parameter to `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` so I can pass the instance to it, but I don't know how to do this.

I'm thinking about using the notification center. I could fire a notification from with the exception handler and listen for it in my AppDelegate, but I'm not sure if that's possible or any cleaner than the static reference way.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not get a reference to the AppDelegate using the `UIApplication` class?

Something like:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] instanceMethod];
```